# How to change default timezone c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I change default timezone on my MVC(c#) web application?
Server located in USA, clients connecting from Turkey...
I'm looking for a global solution for it, as global.asax or webcofig...

I find a method, wrote a static datetime; it adds differences to UTC time zone. But when day light saved it returning wrong time. I need to change it manually and system is too sensitivie. I can't take risk as manual configure...

All clients have same timezone (GMT+2), So no need international things.

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE & SOLUTION:**

```
    public static DateTime DateNow()
    {
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Middle East Standard Time"));
    }
```

Comment: dear anders, that solution not completed; i already saw before. solution says "set timezone information in the web.config and convert your time according to the web.config's timezone." but it doesnt provide method for web config...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        DateTime utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        string zoneID = CurrentUserSession.TimeZoneID // Here you get the current login user session and their TimeZone which you configured in database at the time of user creation. or if you want to get client pc time zone then you have to use javascript and get client pc Timezone

        TimeZoneInfo myZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneID);
        DateTime custDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, myZone);
```